# How to specify class type when using spring kafka template?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My current setup has the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> myKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(stringJsonMessageConverter());

    return factory;
}
```

where stringJsonMessageConverter has

```
@Bean
public StringJsonMessageConverter stringJsonMessageConverter() {
    return new StringJsonMessageConverter(objectMapper());
}
```

to make use of my object mapper

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .registerModule(myCustomJacksonModules())
            .configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
            .configure(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
}
```

With this configuration, i am able to publish as:

```
...
headers = new MessageHeaders(singletonMap(TOPIC, topic));
Foo foo = ....
Message<?> message = new GenericMessage<>(foo, headers);
kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

And consume as:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic",
        groupId = "g1",
        containerFactory = "myKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessageReceived(Foo foo) {
    ... works with foo here
}
```

This works fine in this example if Foo is concrete class. If however Foo is an abstract and what is send as
message are it's subclasses

```
F1 extends Foo; F2 extends Foo ...

... // publisher

headers = new MessageHeaders(singletonMap(TOPIC, topic));
F1 f1 = ....
Message<?> message = new GenericMessage<>(f1, headers);
kafkaTemplate.send(message);

... // Listener

@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic",
        groupId = "g1",
        containerFactory = "myKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessageReceived(Foo foo) {
    ... wont work
}
```

Declaring Foo in my consumer as type would fail but this would work:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic",
        groupId = "g1",
        containerFactory = "myKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessageReceived(Map<String,Object> fooAsMap) {
    ... this works too
}
```

Aside from the option mentioned above which is to use Map, ive also tried the following:

```
- class level kafka listener ([from here)][1]; it still requires method with param of type Map
- custom deserializer registered in object mapper?
```

Is there a way to specify the target type when i send the message?

Comment: by target type you mean any specific POJO object you want to send right?

Comment: yes. in my example that would be F1 as the type.. with the goal that during the conversion from kafka to object it would know that it's F1 even if the listener is declared as Foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the `StringJsonMessageConverter` with a custom `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` where it has the `setTypePrecedence(TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID)`.

Also set the type mappings to map to the desired class, based on the sending type id header (only needed if the producer's class is different to the consumer's class).